# mapreduce.TextInputFormat hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, recordreader

I am a hadoop beginner. I came across [this](http://bigdatacircus.com/2012/08/01/wordcount-with-custom-record-reader-of-textinputformat/) custom RecordReader program which reads 3 lines at a time and outputs the number of times a 3 line input was given to the mapper.

I am able to understand why a RecordReader is used, but I'm not able to see how each InputSplit can contain 3 lines when the input format class is essentially extending the mapreduce.TextInputFormat class.
And as per my understanding the TextInputFormat class emits 1 InputSplit for each line(for each \n).

So how could the RecordReader read 3 lines from each InputSplit? Please someone explain how this is possible.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand the implementation of `TextInputFormat` to discover the answer.

Let's dive into the code. I will speak about the new mapreduce API but the "old" mapred API is quite similar.

As you said, from a user point of view a `TextInputFormat` splits a split into records according to some new line characters. Let's [check the implementation](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/1f2a21ff9b812ec9667ce7561f9c02a45dfe5674/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.java#L42).

You can see that the class is almost empty. The key function is `createRecord` which is defined by `InputFormat`

```
@Override
public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(
        InputSplit split, 
        TaskAttemptContext context
) {
   return new LineRecordReader();
}
```

The general contract is that an InputFormat is used to get a RecordReader. If you look inside `Mapper` and `MapContextImpl` you will see that the mapper only uses the RecordReader to get the next key and value. He does not know anything else.

Mapper:

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  setup(context);
  while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
    map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
  }
  cleanup(context);
```

}

MapContextImpl:

```
@Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  return reader.nextKeyValue();
}
```

Now re-read carefully this link you provided. You will see that:

- `NLinesInputFormat` extends `TextInputFormat` and only override  `createRecordReader`. Basically rather that using a `LineReader` you provide your own `RecordReader`. You want to extends `TextInputFormat` rather than another class higher in the hierarchy because it already takes care of everything that in done at this level and you could need (compression, non-splitable format etc.)
- `NLinesRecordReader` does the real job. In `initialize` it does what is required to get an `InputStream` seeked at the right offset from the provided `InputSplit`. It also create a `LineReader`, the same one that is used by `TextInputFormat`
- In the `nextKeyValue` method you will see that `LineReader.readLine()` is invoked three times to get three lines (plus some logic to properly handle corner cases like a too large record, end of line, end of split)

Hope that it helps you. The key is to understand the overall design of the API and how each part interact with each other.

Comment: Somewhat understood. But this makes me get another seemingly irrelevant doubt- how many `InputSplit`s are generated for say a 1,000,000 line text file? Does a single node setup create only one `InputSplit`?

Comment: [This post](http://dailyhadoopsoup.blogspot.fr/2014/02/mapreduce-inputs-and-splitting.html) might help you. Basically, one split -> one mapper and one HDFS block -> one split (however, splitting can be tuned with properties like `mapred.max.split.size`). When a mapper is started it knows its split and it asks a RecordReader to the InputFormat defined in the Job conf. Then, it runs a while loop calling your map function for each record until the RecordReader return false (ie. end-of-split).